# mongodb query to get average of cities population

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am doing an exercise online and it says:
Please calculate the average population of cities in California (abbreviation CA) and New York (NY) (taken together) with populations over 25,000.

For this problem, assume that a city name that appears in more than one state represents two separate cities.

Please note:
Different states might have the same city name.
A city might have multiple zip codes.

One document:

> db.zips.findOne()

```
{
        "_id" : "92278",
        "city" : "TWENTYNINE PALMS",
        "loc" : [
                -116.06041,
                34.237969
        ],
        "pop" : 11412,
        "state" : "CA"
}
```

My query:

```
db.zips.aggregate([{$group:{ _id: {state: "$state", city: "$city", zip: "$_id"
}, pop: {$sum: "$pop"}}},{$match:{pop:{"$gt":25000}, "_id.state": {$in: ["CA", "
NY"]}}}, {$group: {_id:0, avg: {$avg: "$pop"}}}])
{ "_id" : 0, "avg" : 41485.69565217391 }
```

But it is not correct, what am I missing?

Comment: You ***really*** should bite your way through these exercises yourself. By letting others do the homework part for you (which will make up a part of your grade), you miss the learning effects ***and*** by cheating the grading system you make the certificate less meaningful and valuable for all stakeholders.

Comment: It's ridiculous that the person who want to receive the certificate asks others to solve his own homework. When you are working in some company as a ..developer (orlY?) and somehow the Internet connection is missing, what do you do? Ask your boss to solve it? Or your lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say as a city can have different zip codes, in your query you are taking in account the cities that have different zips as different cities.

So, I would remove the zip part from your first group:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: {state: "$state", city: "$city"}, 
            pop: {$sum: "$pop"}
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            pop:{"$gt":25000}, "_id.state": {$in: ["CA", "NY"]}
        }
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
            _id:0, 
            avg: {$avg: "$pop"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: other question, how can I remove the id in the answer?

Comment: adding the element $project at the end of the aggregation: {$project: {_id:0, avg:1}}

Comment: Weslor. It's good to help others but not in this case. This task the person must solve by himself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code to find out the average population of the state. along with you can find other relevant info as well 
like which is the biggest or smallest city and what population in the same query using the aggregator as below.

```
db.zips.drop()

    db.zips.insert({
    "_id" : "1",
    "city" : "C1",
    "pop" : 100,
    "state" : "CA"
    })

    db.zips.insert({
    "_id" : "2",
    "city" : "C2",
    "pop" : 50,
    "state" : "CA"
    })

    db.zips.insert({
    "_id" : "3",
    "city" : "C3",
    "pop" : 500,
    "state" : "CA"
    })

    db.zips.insert({
    "_id" : "4",
    "city" : "C4",
    "pop" : 80,
    "state" : "CA"
    })

    db.zips.aggregate([{$group:{ _id: {state: "$state", city : "$city"}, pop: {$sum : "$pop"} }},
    { $sort: { pop: 1 } },
    { $group:
    {
    _id : "$_id.state",
    biggestCity:  { $last: "$_id.city" },
    biggestPop:   { $last: "$pop" },
    smallestCity: { $first: "$_id.city" },
    smallestPop:  { $first: "$pop" }
    }
    }

])
```

the whole information you can find in below link.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

-$achin.